# Creating a well structured large SQL database

Tags: sql, database, normalization

I had a single table that contained all of our server's windows event logs in (pulled from a log server).

At first this was ok, as I put more data into it, the slower it became...It is now millions of rows.

So i thought it would be better to break down each server to it's own table, making specific querying that much faster.

The issue is, what if i want to search for an event across all servers?

So I'm coming here for some advice on how to correctly set up my tables.

Below is a CREATE TO.. copy and paste of how each table is structured, replacing 'server1' with the actual name.

```
        USE [Events_Data]
    GO

    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[servername1]    Script Date: 8/18/2017 8:48:59 AM ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[servername1](
        [Message] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Id] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Version] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Qualifiers] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Level] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Task] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Opcode] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Keywords] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [RecordId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [ProviderName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [ProviderId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [LogName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [ProcessId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [ThreadID] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [MachineName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [UserID] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [TimeCreated] [datetime] NULL,
        [ActivityId] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [RelatedActivityID] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [ContainerLog] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [MatchedQueryIDs] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Bookmark] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [LevelDisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [OpcodeDisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [TaskDisplayName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [KeywordsDisplayNames] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Properties] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

    GO
```

I've attached a row of data from a server...each table is very similar except the 'machinename' column is specific to the server that the table holds the events for.

```
Message,Id,Version,Qualifiers,Level,Task,Opcode,Keywords,RecordId,ProviderName,ProviderId,LogName,ProcessId,ThreadID,MachineName,UserID,TimeCreated,ActivityId,RelatedActivityID,ContainerLog,MatchedQueryIDs,Bookmark,LevelDisplayName,OpcodeDisplayName,TaskDisplayName,KeywordsDisplayNames,Properties
Error message whatever,1000,,0,2,100,,3.60288E+16,302366,Application Error,,Application,,,servernameapp1.domain.com,,00:03.0,,,\\servernamelogs\d$\windows-logs\archive-forwardedevents-2017-04-01-05-03-29-167.evtx,,System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventBookmark,Error,Info,Application Crashing Events,Classic,System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty
```

Any help on creating a well structured database that I can query against all tables would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I dont think that it is wise to break down each server into its own table. If anything you should have a table for `servers` and a table for `logs`. You then assign a `log` output to a `server` based on the foreign key `server_id`. This would allow you to show only logs for a specific server.

Comment: The most important three keywords: *data type*, *nullable* and *index*. And no: Do not split this into several tables!

Comment: Like the other people said, you should not split the tables. However, if you usually query for only one server, then this would be a typical use case for partitioning.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I have to grab all the information for auditing purposes, I am by no means a database engineer and I am just trying to get by and learn what I can. I will look into adding some of the changes you have submitted. Thanks again!

Comment: Read a book on information modeling & database design. Please ask a specific question about a specific problem. This is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

WOW. So many things wrong with this, but as a start:

1. Create a Primary Key and Clustered Index on the most commonly used Key column(s) or the artificial key (looks like id in this case?)
2. Change your datatypes... Varchar(MAX) is a string of unlimited length... Probably your Id columns should be Ints and event string columns limited to their reasonable max length.
3. Make required columns non-nullable
4. Create non-clustered indexes on any join / sort / where columns

Do **not** create a table for each server. Just create an index on the ServerId column...

P.S. Are you sure you need all those columns? How are you inserting them? A few look like they are just inputting the type of the Object, eg. System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.EventProperty in the last column. You probably need a .ToString() or something to get the actual value. But I would question if you actually even need all these columns.

Comment: I'm glad to know that i'm on the same sort of wave length as someone else on this, decent answer.

Comment: Agreed! One additional point is that if for some reason the data needs to be chopped up by server (or date or event type or whatever) then use partitioning and let the database engine take care of the mechanics for you. Still a last resort in most cases.